# nodejs Express html

Tags: html, node.js, express

When I use Express framework,I put my ".html" files into folder views,then put ".js" and ".css" files into public.When I run my application,I can get the js and css,but I cann't get the articlecontent.html.The following is my page index.html.

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="articlecontent.html" target="home">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container" class="container" style="height: inherit">
        <iframe id="home" name="home" scrolling="no">content</iframe>
    </div>
</div>

app.get("/",function index(req,res){
    res.render("index.html");
});
```

Comment: Do you have a view and route for articlecontent.html?

Comment: But if I put the articlecontent.html into view,and add a route for articlecontent.html,how can it know change the attribute "src" of iframe.code:<a href="/articlecontent" target="home">Content</a> app.get('/articlecontent',function(req,res){res.render("articlecontent.html")});

Answer (score 1):

The `views` folder is typically meant to store template files; in other words, that folder contains the files that you send out using `res.render()`.

If you want to serve a non-template HTML file, like your `articlecontent.html`, you should place it in the public folder, so it will be served by the `express.static` middleware (the same goes for your `index.html`: if you don't require it to be rendered by a templating engine, you can move it to the public folder as well).

Comment: I see.But if I put the articlecontent.html into view,and add a route for articlecontent.html,how can it know change the attribute "src" of iframe.code:<a href="/articlecontent" target="home">Content</a> app.get('/articlecontent',function(req,res){res.render("articlecontent.html")});

Comment: @BruceWar I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @BruceWar If you want the markup in the file to be data-driven, you'll need to involve a view engine. [`consolidate.js`](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/)'s documentation has a good list of options and the module itself can help with getting any of them working with Express. Related: [`app.engine()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine).

Comment: @robertklep I mean if I put articlecontent.html into view,how can I do?  I want to implment the function that when I click the tag <a>,the tag iframe will direct to articlecontent.html.

Comment: @BruceWar that's something you have to implement on the client side, for instance using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).